# 3 way switches / multiple buildings / no neutral or ground in conduit

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, underground

I am installing two 3 way switches to control lights in my shed.   I have 3/4" conduit in the ground between the two locations.

I DO NOT want to run ground or neutral through the conduit.   Because of space and neutral/ground is available at both locations.

My main panel/meeter is on the side of the shed with a 200amp breaker.
There is sperate conduit to the house that has the wires to feed the main panel in the house basement.

Also on this panel at the shed, I have 4 unused breaker slots and ground and neutral bars.

Both the shed and houser panels have their own grounding rods in the ground based on code.

I am wring lights and outlets in the shed this week.

I want the lights on a 3 way switches.

My plan was to put a breaker in the house panel.   Ground the switch back to the house panel.   Hot to common on that switch.    Then run my two travelers out through the 3/4" conduit to the shed.

Then at the shed...travelers terminate at the 3 way.   This 3 way here common connects to my light.   The the neutral of my lights then terminates back to the panel here at the shed neutral bar.   The grounds of the lights and the 3 way switch at the shed terminate at the shed panel grounding bar.

Both sides are grounded.    The lights have a path to neutral and ground.   But no neutral or ground is in the conduit.

Now as far as the four open breaker slots in the shed panel.    2 will be for outlets in the shed and two will be for a hot tub in the future.

Any questions ?
Is this a bad idea ?

Comment: Is this the conduit that feeds power to the shed or some other conduit for the light-switch.

Comment: They are separate pieces.  There are three pieces of conduit in total. One is the main feed from the shed panel to the panel in the basement. One is for low voltage such as cable or phone lines. And the third is a smaller 3/4 in conduit for running 3-way switches

Comment: What type of conduit is in the ground?

Comment: Schedule 40.    It was put in by an electrician and a electrical inspection was done at that time.

Comment: You want to violate NEC 300.3, to save the cost of 1 wire.  You wouldn't bootleg neutral off ground, but you feel OK bootlegging neutral from a different *panel*... which is just as bad really.

Comment: Not bootleg anything.      All grounds and neutral are being used

Answer (score 3):

#### Neutral is not Ground

They connect (bonded) in one location, usually the main panel. But they are not "the same". In particular, there are a number of instances where "ground can be connected to any place you have ground", but that is never the case for neutral. That is actually *mostly* for "retrofit ground" - i.e., you didn't have ground before and want to add it to an existing circuit, but there may be other instances where it is permitted. But you can't do that for neutral. Never.

#### Conduit as Ground

Rigid metal conduit (maybe some other metal types, I get confused) doubles as your ground (*but never neutral*). Unfortunately, based on comments you have PVC conduit, so you need a ground wire.

#### All Current Must Go Together

This is the key. On an unswitched circuit, that means hot & neutral together. On an old switch loop, that means hot & switched hot together. **On a 3-way circuit, that means travelers and neutral or travelers and switched hot together**. This is the key issue - you can't rationalize your way around it. No matter how you wire it (except smart switches) you will need 3 wires in the conduit (and possibly a 4th for ground).

The issue is *not* having a path for power to get back "home" - any neutral would do that. It is to have the current carrying conductors matched to avoid eddy currents. In addition, this would be guaranteed to trip any GFCI. You generally don't need GFCI on lighting, but that is simply because the life-safety issues are not nearly as common (cost-benefit), **not** to allow for crazy wiring schemes like this one.

#### Actual Real Danger!

There is actually one place where this could result in a serious problem - i.e., it isn't just code being nitpicky. If your 3-way lights are on and using neutral via the shed subpanel, and you turn off the feed to the subpanel to work on it, **you will have power flowing through the neutral in the subpanel.** In other words, you'd be working on a live panel without knowing it, which is an incredibly dangerous situation.

Comment: The shed panel is the main panel with the meter.    The main 200 amp breaker at the shed disconnects the house panel and the four breakers at the shed.

Comment: I may have it backwards for your particular configuration. But the end result is as I understand what you are describing would have hot from one panel (or subpanel) and neutral from the other panel (or subpanel). You can't do that, because in addition to being a clear code violation, it can result in someone getting burned. Literally.

Answer (score 0):

AIUI code requires earth and neutral at all new switch boxes, you're not allowed to use the neutral from a different circuit.

So yes it's a bad idea and there's no way to make it work.

Comment: Neutral all goes back to a common neutral bar.   It's not divided up by circuit

Comment: once it leaves the breaker box it's divided.  code says neutral must run parallel to the hot it serves in the same raceway